# Is there a way to manually post to a rest webservice using a browser

Tags: xml, browser, rest, post

Is there a way to manually post an xml to a webservice using a browser something like:

```
POST http://url/Endpoint <xml file text>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With browser add-ons - yes. For example "Tamper Data" for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/

See also "Poster" add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2691/

Answer (score 4):

You could use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) on the [command line](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/181):

```
curl -d '@/home/test.xml' http://url/Endpoint
```

or directly:

```
curl -d '<hello/>' http://url/Endpoint
```

Answer (score 2):

> [REST Client plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9780/)